# How do I call two onClick JavaScript calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small request for some help, how would I be able to call in two onClick calls within the same anchor tags?

I have the following:

> onClick="wButton(this.id)"
>   onClick='window.location="#top"'

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot duplicate attributes in HTML. However, you can separate the statements within the `onclick` with a `;` to execute them both:

```html
onClick="wButton(this.id); window.location='#top'"
```

However you should note that the `onclick` attribute is very outdated. You should look in to using unobtrusive event handlers instead. In plain JS it would look like this:

```js
document.querySelector('#yourElement').addEventListener('click', function() {
  wButton(this.id);
  window.location = '#top';
});
```

In jQuery it would look like this:

```js
$('#yourElement').click(function() {
  wButton(this.id);
  window.location = '#top';
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much Rory!

Comment: No problem, glad to help